# React Native headerBackTitleVisible: false not working in Expo SDK 48

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using Expo SDK 48 (after upgrading from 46), my issue is that I had a bunch of options containing `headerBackTitle: "..."` or `headerBackTitleVisible: false` in my React Navigation, but seems to be not working in the new update. Looked at docs on React Nav but didn't find any breaking change sooo... have anyone encountered the same problem?

code:
`options={{ headerBackTitleVisible: false, headerTitle: "Detail" }}` (headerTitle works fine :))

Comment: Your code should be working with `headerBackTitleVisible` set to false, are you sure  are placing it inside the correct stack options? Can you show us a snippet of the config that you have?

Comment: `<HomeStack.Group>
                <HomeStack.Screen name="Courses" component={Course} options={{ ...miniHeaderOptions }} />
                <HomeStack.Screen name="SingleCourse" component={SingleCourse} options={{ ...miniHeaderOptions, headerBackTitleVisible: false, headerTitle: "Detail", headerTransparent: true }} />
            </HomeStack.Group>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the options inside of `HomeStack.Group`,

```
<HomeStack.Group screenOptions={{ headerBackTitleVisible: false, ... }}>
...
```

Comment: Yes this approach seems to be working but it is a bit unfriendly :D but yeah thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem when I use `@react-navigation/native-stack`, my workaround is switch to `@react-navigation/stack`

```
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.12",
"@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.16",
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to add one more thing, it works for native-stack too if the headerBAckTitle is the previous screen name and not "Back".